# Spring mvc resources not works

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I created ,with Eclipse Luna, a simple Spring MVC Project but it doesn't works if i add mvc:resources in springConfig-servlet.xml. I have this errors in Tomcat:

```
 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
Avvertenza: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringStore/] in   DispatcherServlet with name 'springConfig'
```

Where am I doing wrong?Thanks

This is the structure of my project

[image]

Web.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>SpringStore</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>springConfig</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>springConfig</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

springConfig-Servlet code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
</beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(){
    return "index";     
}//welcome

}
```

The contents of the file index.jsp is very long and I don't write it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are missing below entries in your **springConfig-Servlet.xml** file.

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: If i add mvc:annotation-driver the project starts but it doen't load the css file and the images.

Comment: how you are accessing css files from your jsp? can you paste the code here?

Comment: All the contents of the folder resources is not load.
In jsp: <link href="/resources/css/stile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Please paste your code for accessing css/images files from index.jsp file,there might be some problem with it.

Comment: For ex. this is an image in jsp:<div class="testata"><img src="/resources/images/testata.png" width="100" height="100" /></div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65138/discussion-between-re350-and-alex).